# Converting PSD to Magento theme

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I know how to convert PSD to HTML and also know PHP. I'm new to Magento and learning it now.

I want to learn how to convert PSD to Magento theme or what steps to be followed.

I searched Google but couldn't find any promising or proper solution.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento or this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is, first create HTML file of your PSD. Now this depends on which page of the site you are building. There are basically 3 different types of wire frame structures that you can use. Depending on the content of you site they could be either,

1) One columned page

2) Two Columned page. Which is further divided into two columns with left bar and two columns with right bar.

3) Three columned page.

All three (or four) types of structures have some basic class and div tag structure. You can see the structure by going to the Magento demo site and viewing the source of the page. Use those classes and div names/ids in the HTML you create.

After the HTML is done, you can then just copy the code and replace it with appropriate Magento files. And yes, knowing the file structure of Magento is a huge help.

This shall get you started.